# Sonarqube and NDepend? How to get data from NDepend during a build in TFS?

Tags: sonarqube, ndepend

I have a build in TFS 2013 running in a controller with NDepend installed. Our sonarqube instance is with the NDepend plugin installed.

From the build I set it to run the sonarqube runner MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe with these parameters:

```
begin /k:Test /n:"Test" /v:1.0 /d:sonar.cs.ndepend.projectPath="C:\TMP\TEST.ndproj" /d:sonar.cs.ndepend.reportPath="C:\TMP\ndepend-report.xml"
```

> Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.command.CommandException: NDepend
>   execution failed with exit code: -532462766 [command:
>   C:\tmp\NDepend_6.2.1.8630\Integration\SonarQube\NDepend.SonarQube.RuleRunner.exe
>   C:\TMP\TEST.ndproj
>   C:\TMP\ndepend-report.xml

So in the end of the build I can see this message and nothing else:

```
ERROR:
 ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully
 Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
```

How can I figure out what is wrong with it? If I run the command in my build server using CMD window it works, but running from Sonarqube runner it fails.

Comment: Normally this step by step tutorial should answer all questions, have you followed it?  http://www.ndepend.com/docs/sonarqube-integration-ndepend

Comment: Yes, I followed that... it's very clear the information. Today I restarted the server and now it works... that was the problem.

Comment: But not the issue is when we try to run NDepend from Sonarqube runner, I've updated the description above.

Comment: Fabito, we may have a fix for this, could you come back to us at support@ndepend.com

Comment: I sent an email for you, got the .jar replaced to a newer but still got the same error. Is there some way to have more details about the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I got it to work.

It was a silly mistake, my build service controller was running under a service account, and **I needed to run NDepend first under that account to activate it**. 

Done that all started working as expected.

Comment: Glad this is fixed :)